# Passing a factory to symfony 2 service

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class which is dependent on a DB connection, something like this:

```
class Test 
{
   private $conn;
   public function __construct(Connection $conn) {
       $this->conn = $conn;
   }
}
```

The service for this could look like this:

```
 services:
      service.test:
          class: Test
          arguments:
             - ["@database_connection"]
```

Now, I'd like to pass my own connection service / object that at startup creates a `Connection`. But I can't pass it as an argument as it wants a `Connection` object, not a factory.

How can I best approach this?

I've tried adding a `setConnection` on the `Test` class, but it would be nicer to keep the current definition and service intact.

Comment: Could you change your class to accept the factory as dependency?

Comment: I could, but I'm more interested in solutions that leave the class as it is..just curious

Comment: I see. I think there might be a way. Could you add the factory code and it's registration in yaml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually ready solution for that in Symfony's Service Container.

Your `database_connection` service should be configured to use a factory to create its instance. That would be something like this:

```
services:
    database_connection:
        class:   Connection
        factory: [ConnectionFactory, createConnection]
```

And if the factory is a service too, it might look like this:

```
services:
    database_connection:
        class:   Connection
        factory: ["@connection_factory", createConnection]
```

More information about that can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html).